# JPA queries memory leak?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, memory-leaks, eclipselink

We are profiling our application using `Jprofiler` to solve memory leaks and came across following observations:

We ran our application on the same data set to check and took multiple snapshots after marking Heap to see the Classes contributing to memory leak.

[image]

The `byte[]`, `String`, `int[]` after checking their allocations all point to `JPA` queries. For example the allocation Hotspots for `byte[]` all point to query results :

`QuerImpl.getSingleResult`,

`QueryImpl.getResultList`

`EnitiyManger.find` :

[image]

Similar results were found for allocations of `String`, `jav.util.HashMap$Node`:

[image]

The one query on JPA which shows significant allocation is `checkResourceID` in `Dao` class:

```
@Stateless
@EJB(name = "java:global/ResourceProceduresDaoImpl", beanInterface = ResourceProceduresDao.class)
public class ResourceProceduresDaoImpl<R> implements ResourceProceduresDao<R> {

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/M2M_RESOURCES")
    private DataSource ds;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EM")
    EntityManager em;
    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ResourceProceduresDaoImpl.class);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");

    public void create(R resource) {
        em.persist(resource);
        em.flush();
    }

    public R retrieve(Class type, String resourceID) {
        logger.info("ResourceProceduresDaoImpl class=" + type + " resourceID=" + resourceID);
        Object obj = em.find(type, resourceID);
        // logger.info("ResourceProceduresDaoImpl obj="+obj);
        return (R) obj;
    }

    public void update(R resource) {
        em.merge(resource);
    }

    public void delete(R resource) {
        if (!em.contains(resource))
            resource = em.merge(resource);
        em.remove(resource);
    }        
public boolean checkResourceID(String resourceID) {
                boolean ifExists = false;
             
                if (em.createNamedQuery("ResourcePCM.findByResourceID", ResourceParentChildMapping.class)
                    .setParameter("resourceId", resourceID).getSingleResult() == null) {
                    
                        ifExists = true;
                    } 
    
    ..//
                return ifExists;
            }
```

The JPA for `ResourcePCM` :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="\"RESOURCE_PCM\"",schema="\"RESOURCES\"")
    @NamedQueries({
       @NamedQuery(name="ResourcePCM.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM ResourcePCM r"),
       @NamedQuery(name="ResourcePCM.findByResourceID", query="SELECT r FROM ResourcePCM r where r.resourceID = :resourceId")
    
    })
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
            name = "generateResourceID", 
            procedureName = "generateResourceID", 
            parameters = { 
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name = "input"), 
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, type = String.class, name = "output")
            }
        )
    public class ResourcePCM implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        @Id
        @Column(name="\"resourceID\"")
        private String resourceID;
        
        @Column(name="\"structuredResourceID\"")
        private String structuredResourceID;
    
        @Column(name="\"parentID\"")
        private String parentID;
    
        @Column(name="\"resourceType\"")
        private Integer resourceType;
        
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinColumn(name="\"resourceID\"",referencedColumnName="\"resourceID\"")
        private Set<ResourceACP> resourceACP;

..///
}
```

So like this only in queries there are significant allocations of memory and I am unable to figure out the cause.

Is it the `JPA` ? Or the way `EntityManager` is invoked ?

PS: I use `JNDI` lookup for my Beans rather than injection with `@EJB` or `@Inject`, if this would make a difference ?

**EDIT**

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="EM" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/M2M_RESOURCES</jta-data-source>
            <class>package.jpa.ResourceBase1</class>
            <class>package.jpa.ResourceBase2</class>
            <class>package.jpa.ResourceBase3</class>
            <class>package.jpa.ResourceBase4</class>
            <class>package.jpa.ResourceBase5</class>
            <class>package.jpa.ResourceBase6</class>  

..///

            <!-- Converters -->
            <class>package.mapping.DBJsonConverter</class>       
            <properties>                                                
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="PostgreSQL" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**EDIT2:**

Incoming References to `byte[] :`

[image]

Incoming references expanded:

[image]

The difference between two snapshots taken between 5k request and 10k request load:

[image]

**postgresql-ds.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:/RESOURCES" pool-name="RESOURCES" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://[hostname]:[port]/[schema]</connection-url>
        <driver>postgresql-42.2.5.jar</driver>
        <pool> 
            <min-pool-size>200</min-pool-size> <max-pool-size>400</max-pool-size> 
            <prefill>true</prefill> 
        </pool> 
        <security>
            <user-name>[userName]</user-name>
            <password>[password]</password>
        </security>
        <timeout>
            <blocking-timeout-millis>800</blocking-timeout-millis>
        </timeout>
        <statement>
            <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
            <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

Comment: Off the top of my head I could think of the following scenarios which you might want to look for: 1) This is the 1st level cache of a long lived EntityManager which is used to keep track of changes to attached entities. 2) It's just an awful lot of data the query loads. 3) You've enabled the query cache so EclipseLink tries to get cached data from already executed queries.

Comment: You need to be careful here. "Using a lot of memory" is not "leaking memory". Objects created by JPA may live for a long time without that being a leak. How much memory is your application using and for how long does it keep increasing its footprint? Weeks or just minutes?

Comment: @Thomas : 1) We have a single `Dao` class (posted in question) which has an EM injected, and that is being used for all 30-40 Entities. For clarification I am adding `persistent.xml` in question. So different classes get this `Dao` instance to call DB query methods. What would qualify as a Long lived EntityManger here ? 2)  It's not much. There will be one or two matches by query result 3) As you can see in `JPA` we haven't explicitly set `QueryCache`. We are running on defualt settings. Should I look someplace else too ? I have edited the question

Comment: @ewramner : I checked difference in multiple snapshots every 1000 requests. The difference increases steadily. If I ran a big load and memory consumption in each pod went till full `16GB` and it stayed there. I enabled GC logs to see, after every peak the base of memory consumed increases in `MB`s but like this in hours it is full

Comment: The issue might be that you seem to effectively be using the same entity manager which over time may accumulate a lot of entity references. I'm no EclipseLink expert but you might want to look at either how to restrict the lifetime of an entity manager (e.g. get the EntityManagerFactory instead and create a new EM for each transaction) or the amount of memory used by the first level cache.

Comment: Your usage isn't quite described at all. How many entities are you reading in, what are the sizes of those entities, and are they being cached or held onto by the application for an extended period? Tracking what is holding onto the memory directly should give you a clue as to the cause and how to fix it - What you've shown though doesn't mention JPA/EclipseLink classes though, so doesn't seem like it is the EntityManager - what you've shown doesn't involve a byte[] at all, so its hard to guess what is involved.

Comment: @Chris: I checked the JPA/Entities count is not increasing between two Heap Snapshots, however the `byte[]`, `String` are the major increases in memory. So I have looked into incoming references to `byte[]` and attached a screenshot in the question (check EDIT2). The allocations for these `byte[]`, `String` point to the queries executed as mentioned in question.

Comment: Those byte[]/string[] are not something generally used in JPA, and are not indicated in any of your entities - I would look at your JDBC datasource setup and config, especially as your images show postgres/JBoss statement caching classes. Again though, the profiler should show exactly what is holding onto those memory objects. I would guess you have statement caching enable at the driver/server level.

Comment: @Chris : `String`, `List<String>` is being used in our Entities. We use `share-prepared-statements` is our Datasource setting. I have added `postgresql-ds.xml` in the question (Edit 2). Could this be the sole cause ? But it has to be a memory leak because memory gets full no matter how much RAM is increased

Comment: Check again what is holding string[] and byte[] as I don’t think they have to do with your entities. I’m also not sure of your dataSource settings - did performance tuning really require 200+ DB connections, with each having 100 statements cached?